# The direction of sphere surrounding the player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok here is my code

```
 RaycastHit hit;
 if (Physics.SphereCast(
          this.transform.position,
          0.5f,
          this.transform.position,
          out hit))
        {
            if(hit.collider.tag=="example tag")
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
```

What I want to do is move the sphere along the gameObject attached to it

the gameObject is always moving forward,  that is, the positive z axis is always increasing,

so i want to keep a uniform size of sphere surrounding my gameObject

I think the mistake is with the directional vector?

can anyone help me with this. I tried searching over internet for hours ,but no luck, Thanks!

Comment: Sorry @JoeBlow I thought I did

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it's possible you want

> transform.forward

there's an example of "transform.forward" right on the doco:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html

Comment: Hey I found a solution for it ,did this by using Ray 

`Ray ray= new Ray(this.transform.position, this.transform.forward);
 if (Physics.SphereCast(ray,50f,out hit,20f))`

Comment: The previous method by which I was using,it was increasing the z axis,so yeah you are right ,I'll try your method as well ,Thanks! @JoeBlow ,you have always been a savior.

Comment: I have already done that,may I know why you are insisting me to delete "this"?